# Spring boot application in netbeans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netbeans-8

I installed Netbeans 8.0.2, then installed gradle plugin, and created new gradle empty project. Then copied *.java and *.gradle files from https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot.git. When call gradle build - all ok, jar created and works. Build from netbeans menu works fine too.

But in java editor of Netbeans lines that contains gradle dependencies are marked as incorrect. For example imports like this

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
```

are marked that does not exists. And dependencies are empty (in projects tab). How to fix this?

**Update.** I don't know what was wrong that time, but now all works fine. If there is a such problem try reload netbeans, check environment variables like $GRADLE_HOME, reboot computer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's not really a question here.